# Helm 3, ingress-nginx-controller not updating after changing values in helm resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am using helm to configure my local dev env. My configuration worked pre-Kubernetes v1.22, but due to the recent Docker Desktop updates, I'd now like to support Kubernetes v1.22.

I have followed Kubernetes-specific migration examples, but I am encountering issues when attempting to upgrade my ingress-nginx-controller. I was using ingress-nginx v0.45, but based on their version support table [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) it looks like I need at least v1.0 in order to work with Kubernetes v1.22

Looking at my ingress-nginx-controller logs in docker desktop I can see the following after running a helm install:

[image]

My deployment resource looked like this:

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.27.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.45.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.45.0@sha256:c4390c53f348c3bd4e60a5dd6a11c35799ae78c49388090140b9d72ccede1755
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
            - --default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/rs-ssl-secret
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/configmap-nginx
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

I then updated the version numbers:

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.10
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.5
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.5@sha256:c4390c53f348c3bd4e60a5dd6a11c35799ae78c49388090140b9d72ccede1755
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
            - --default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/rs-ssl-secret
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/configmap-nginx
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

After making the changes, and running a helm uninstall followed by a helm install I get the exact same logs, indicating that the nginx-ingress-controller is still using v0.45.0

Is there something I'm missing? It almost feels like the changes I'm making to my deployment resource aren't appearing in my install. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm not the most experienced Helm/Kubernetes user

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would change the version by specifying this in your installation command.

For example

```sh
helm install ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --version 4.0.15 \
  --generate-name
```

> --version string               specify a version constraint for the chart version to use. This constraint can be a specific tag (e.g. 1.1.1) or it may reference a valid range (e.g. ^2.0.0). If this is not specified, the latest version is used

You can check out the docs on [helm install](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options). Maybe its also worth checking the [offical installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

If you want to have that chart locally for some reason, download it from git.

```sh
curl -fsSLO https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/download/helm-chart-4.0.15/ingress-nginx-4.0.15.tgz
tar -xf ingress-nginx-4.0.15.tgz
```

You can also add the repo locally.

```sh
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --version 4.0.15 ...
```

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately the install command I am running looks quite different to this, I am running the following:

helm install localdev --wait --timeout 3000s -f foo-values.yaml -n localdev -namespace localdev helm --create-namespace

Comment: You are just providing additional flags, it seems.  Or is localdev the chart locally saved?

Comment: Localdev is a local chart I believe

Comment: Then you can pull the version of the chart you need and save it locally. Or you install from upstream which I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you for the help!, I'll give your suggestions a try and see if I can make this work